# Installing php_apc.dll on wampserver

Tags: php, wamp, apc

I need your help. I'm trying to install php_apc.dll into my 
php directory.

So far this is what i've done:

I copied php_apc.dll to c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext. I've also restarted the server several times.

But when i checked

```
 http://localhost/?phpinfo=1
```

There wasnt any evidence of APC Extension Installation.

Please what i'm i doing wrong?
I'll be most delighted with your answers, comments and suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the tutorial [How to install APC on Wamp](http://blog.lardev.com/2011/07/06/install-apc-on-wamp-server/).

It seems you didnt add extention line in `php.ini`

Comment: Now i have added

        ;extension = php_apc.dll
        ;

in php.ini file but still nothing is showing the php_apc extension.

Comment: i dont use Wamp, please check the that insturction above

Comment: Remove the semicolon. That's a comment character.

Comment: Restart Wamp (not apache or mysql, but wamp)