# APC not displayed on phpinfo() and not working either

Tags: php, wamp, apc, php-extension

I have followed these tutorials
[Installing php_apc.dll on wampserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916600/installing-php-apc-dll-on-wampserver) and
http://blog.lardev.com/2011/07/06/install-apc-on-wamp-server/

to install APC on my wamp server. When I try to see the extensions on the wamp>php>extensions it displays the loaded extension `php_apc` and in php.ini I have set the following parameters for APC:

```
[APC]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 64M
apc.max_file_size = 10M
apc.stat = 1
```

But when i visited on `localhost/?phpinfo=1`
I can't find the apc loaded and the apc functions are not working.

I am using `PHP Version 5.3.13`

Comment: Have you looked at the `apache error log' and the `php error log` and even the `Windows Event log` for some clues. Have you checked that you have the correct version of APC and that it is compiled with the correct version of the comiler

Comment: The PHP 5.3.13 that comes with WAMPServer was compiled with  MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008).  You need to make sure the APC.dll was also compiled with that compiler.  Also make sure it is the Thread Safe version.