# what is opcode and data cache in php

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, apc, akeneo

I am installing Akeneo PIM. It is based on the Symfony2 framework.

It has some prerequisites. Some I understood, and some were confusing.

I installed Zend opcache in WAMP, and in phpinfo it is showing, but I do not know what data cache is in php.

I need help for this.....

I am getting this error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch() in D:\wamp\www\akeneo\vendor\doctrine\cache\lib\Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache.php on line 40
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0140  139760  {main}( )   ..\app.php:0
2   0.4300  334232  Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle( )  ..\app.php:24
3   0.4300  334344  Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot( )    ..\bootstrap.php.cache:2253
4   84.9849 830408  Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer( ) ..\bootstrap.php.cache:2222
5   157.3350    19333112    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp( )    ..\bootstrap.php.cache:2451
6   157.4190    19379904    Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\CacheWarmer\ProxyCacheWarmer->warmUp( ) ..\CacheWarmerAggregate.php:47
7   157.4330    19380208    Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata( ) ..\ProxyCacheWarmer.php:69
8   159.3501    20279512    Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor( ) ..\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:114
9   159.3561    20283608    Pim\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Doctrine\ArrayApcCache->fetch( )   ..\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:207
10  159.3561    20283632    Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider->fetch( )   ..\ArrayApcCache.php:54
11  159.3561    20283656    Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider->getNamespacedId( ) ..\CacheProvider.php:78
12  159.3561    20283688    Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider->getNamespaceVersion( ) ..\CacheProvider.php:147
13  159.3561    20284072    Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache->doFetch( )  ..\CacheProvider.php:174
```

Comment: Please let us know if you succeed in doing what you want. If you think that one of the answers helped you or can help someone else in the future, please consider voting & marking it.

Answer (score 1):

You should required to install `APC`, a php extension  on your "wamp". I think [Installing php_apc.dll on wampserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916600/installing-php-apc-dll-on-wampserver) will help you to install `APC` on wamp for windows.

Comment: can we install opc and apc both on wamp

Comment: I am not sure about that but I think you should read this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224798/how-to-use-php-opcache].

Answer (score 1):

Akeneo requires 2 types of cache : one for accelerating code execution, the other one for data caching.

If you use PHP >= 5.5, consider using ZendOPcache and apcu. Note that ZendOPcache is most of the time installed with PHP, but you will sometimes need to enable it on your own.

If you use PHP < 5.5, consider using apc and apcu.

To make sure that both cache are enabled you can use a simple PHP script with a `phpinfo();` call in it. Tips: don't use `php -i` in your shell to verify this, PHP accelerators are sometimes disabled in CLI mode... For Zend OPcache, you can also use a web page such as the one proposed by Rasmus here : https://github.com/rlerdorf/opcache-status

Last but not least, I do not recommand to use Zend OPcache for development. First, you probably don't need more performance when developping, and second, you'll probably waste your time trying to figure out if code errors are due to cache or not (for instance, if your Zend OPcache configuration is very agressive and does not verify code changes in your PHP files...).